# How to import Javascript module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use http://spin.js.org/ to create a spinner on my site that starts spinning when an AJAX post fires and stops when it completes. I'm struggling to get the spinner working at all, though.

I have a node app and am templating with EJS. Under the usage section, spin.js's website says:

```
import {Spinner} from 'spin.js';

var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 38, // The length of each line
  width: 17, // The line thickness
  radius: 45, // The radius of the inner circle
  scale: 1, // Scales overall size of the spinner
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  color: '#ffffff', // CSS color or array of colors
  fadeColor: 'transparent', // CSS color or array of colors
  opacity: 0.25, // Opacity of the lines
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  fps: 20, // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback in IE 9
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
  left: '50%', // Left position relative to parent
  shadow: none, // Box-shadow for the lines
  position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
};

var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

I'm not sure where the `import {Spinner} from 'spin.js'` is supposed to go? I've searched around a lot and haven't been able to find out how to actually implement this. I found [this example of a jquery plugin for spin.js](https://gist.github.com/its-florida/1290439) but I'm struggling with that one as well. Any help would be much appreciated!

As of right now, this is what I have:

```
<div id="spinnerContainer" class="spinner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color: Gray; color:black;">
</div>

<script src="/scripts/spin.js/spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var opts = {
      lines: 20, // The number of lines to draw
      length: 0, // The length of each line
      width: 15, // The line thickness
      radius: 42, // The radius of the inner circle
      scale: 0.85, // Scales overall size of the spinner
      corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
      color: '#41d62b', // CSS color or array of colors
      fadeColor: 'transparent', // CSS color or array of colors
      opacity: 0.05, // Opacity of the lines
      rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
      direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
      speed: 1, // Rounds per second
      trail: 74, // Afterglow percentage
      fps: 20, // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback in IE 9
      zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
      className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
      top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
      left: '50%', // Left position relative to parent
      shadow: 0, // Box-shadow for the lines
      position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
    };

    var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
</script>
```

The script to load in spin.js is finding the file correctly, but then I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` referencing the line `export { Spinner };` from spin.js

I also get an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined` which I assume is related to the error above but I'm not sure.

Comment: where is your `foo` element add your `html ` too, and above all provide the exception you are facing when you try to run it

Comment: Actually it should work. Have you downloaded this library to your `node_modules`? Also it requires either browsers that support javascript modules or using webpack.

Comment: @Sergey Yes it's in node_modules. I added my HTML and JS code referencing the file

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Added code

Comment: Of course you are getting error. You've removed importing of spinner.js.
They've mentioned that you need to use webpack or rollup to deal with `import``

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps all you want is to use a [CDN version](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/spin.js/) if you aren't set up to manage imports

```js
    var opts = {
      lines: 20, // The number of lines to draw
      length: 0, // The length of each line
      width: 15, // The line thickness
      radius: 42, // The radius of the inner circle
      scale: 0.85, // Scales overall size of the spinner
      corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
      color: '#41d62b', // CSS color or array of colors
      fadeColor: 'transparent', // CSS color or array of colors
      opacity: 0.05, // Opacity of the lines
      rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
      direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
      speed: 1, // Rounds per second
      trail: 74, // Afterglow percentage
      fps: 20, // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback in IE 9
      zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
      className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
      top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
      left: '50%', // Left position relative to parent
      shadow: 0, // Box-shadow for the lines
      position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
    };

    var target = document.getElementById('spinnerContainer');
    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/2.3.2/spin.js"></script>
<div id="spinnerContainer" class="spinner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color: Gray; color:black;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error open the CDN file from @charlietfl answer copy it and replace it with your spin.js file. It will work.